# Apply class depending on media query screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap. I have a `btn-group`. I want the `btn-group` and `btn-group-justified` classes added for screens at or above `768px`, and the `btn-group-vertical` class applied for screens at or below `767px`. How can I do this?

Comment: Easiest? That's debatable, but for me the easiest would be to have both button groups in the markup and hide and show them based on meeting media queries.

Comment: Buttons inside have `id`s, so I'm not eager to duplicate them.

Comment: You could use JavaScript based on `window.width`.

Comment: There's no way to apply all the properties of a class in CSS?

Comment: What element are you adding the btn-group to? or do you need the `btn-group` element to have the class `btn-group-justified` for screens at or above `768px`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery implementation. If you can't change the IDs to classes on your buttons, this is probably the best way I can think of to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var changeWidth = function(){
    if ( $(window).width() < 768 ){
    $('.btn-group-justified').removeClass('btn-group-justified').addClass('btn-group-vertical');
    } else {
      $('.btn-group-vertical').removeClass('btn-group-vertical').addClass('btn-group-justified');
    }
  };
  $(window).resize(changeWidth);
});
```

Comment: Note: the second to last line with the resize function should not have parenthesis after the changeWidth. Otherwise it will run only once on the page ever instead of each time the window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap's utility class.  (.visible-xs)

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

You basically create contents that will only be visible if current screen is below 768px. And then add the class you want.